# using percentage for font size for text inside divs so that the divs fit perfectly in my nav?

Tags: html, css, font-size, percentage

the question that I have today is how do i use percentages for the font size within the **divs** within my **nav** so that those **divs** fit perfectly within the **nav**? I usually use pixels, and know how to do this using **px**, but I want to learn how to use percentages so that my webpage resizes appropriately in screens of different sizes.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>The Broker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="Real Estate Agent Toronto" name="keywords">
        <meta content="Homepage of a real estate agent in Toronto" name="description">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="Images/Remax80H.png">
            <span class="HeadButton">Home</span>
            <span class="HeadButton">Property Listings</span>
            <span class="HeadButton">Sitemap</span>
            <span class="HeadButton">Contact me</span>
            <span class="HeadButton">About me</span>
            <img src="Images/Profile80H.png">
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div class="NavButton">
                Home
            </div>
            <div class="NavButton">
                Property Listings
            </div>
            <div class="NavButton">
                Sitemap
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            Something
        </main>
        <footer>
            Something
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
Author: Dharmesh Sujeeun
Student ID: 300-912-000
Purpose: Project for COMP213 course at Centennial College.
First Created: December 3 2016
Last Modified: December 3 2016
*/

/*
Color Palette:


*/

@font-face {
    font-family: Alcubierre;
    src: url(fonts/Alcubierre/Alcubierre.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: CaviarDreams;
    src: url(fonts/CaviarDreams/CaviarDreams.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Capsuula;
    src: url(fonts/Capsuula/Capsuula.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Unique;
    src: url(fonts/Unique/Unique.ttf);
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CBE3F9;
}

.HeadButton {
    font-family: "Alcubierre", sans-serif;
    color: darkslategray;
    font-size: 150%;
    vertical-align: 110%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #DFE5EA;
}

.NavButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #DFE5EA;
    color: darkslategray;
    font-family: "Alcubierre", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 76%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #DEFAFB;
    padding: 2%;
}

footer {
    height: 96%;
    width: 96%;
    background-color: #CBE3F9;
    padding: 2%;
}

img {
    padding: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately responsive text is not as easy as using percentages for the font-size. It's alot more complex and either requires loads of media queries or Javascript.

Comment: Oh okay, should i just stick to pixels then? And center the website (for larger resolution monitors)? Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

well you don't need to use percentage for the font-size .
you have some other ways :

```
font-size:20em
```

or

```
font-size:20vw
```

however you may need to use media to make full responsive website.

and here's a table of all units:

**em**   Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

**ex**  Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used)

**ch**  Relative to width of the "0" (zero)

**rem** Relative to font-size of the root element

**vw**  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport

**vh**  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

**vmin**    Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension

**vmax**    Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension

Comment: Thank you for answering. :)

Comment: lol i tried to upvote your answer but it won't let me, sorry... and thanks for the update, I will try out the 'vw' or 'vh' tomorrow, i feel those might help me accomplish what I am seeking to do. I will let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are overhauling your font structure, you may read up on `rem`. It uses font scaling which can be defined by the user (not just simple zoom) to increase/decrease font sizes. At normal zoom, 1rem = 10px. If you design your divs, etc to use rem, then it'll scale with your fonts. This feels like the opposite of what you are attempting, but might be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will be sure to check it out tomorrow. I will let you know how it goes!